# docker-compose failed to run the container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using this `docker-compose.yml` file to build an image.

Problem is when I don't use the `docker-compose.yml` instead use the usual `docker build` command, it works fine. But when I use the same `Dockerfile` to build the using the `docker-compose` it doesn't work.

This is my `Dockerfile`

```
# Use an official node runtime as a parent image
FROM node:8

WORKDIR /app/

# Install dependencies
COPY package.json /app/

RUN npm install

# Add rest of the client code
COPY . /app/

EXPOSE 3000

CMD npm start
```

and this is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  frontend:
    build: ./my-app
    ports:
      - 80:3000
    command: npm start
```

**Container exited right after it creates when using the docker-compose**

Can someone please help me?

[Update]

This is the error I am getting

[image]

Comment: Does it output anything?  If you build the image outside of Compose, how do you (successfully) build and run it?  (The only obvious thing is the `NODE_ENV` setting; you're overriding `command:` to the same thing as in the image [and you could remove it], and your `volumes:` are targeting a different path so leaving the image code intact [and you could remove it].)

Comment: So you are suggesting to remove `command:` and `volumes:` and `environment:` ?

Comment: Removing `command:`, `volumes:`, and the `networks:` block at the end should all be safe and cause no difference in what you're running.  I'd be surprised if the `environment:` setting caused problems, but it's the one thing that's obviously different from just `docker run -p 80:3000 yourimage`.

Comment: What about my `Dockerfile` does it look fishy?

Comment: Mechanically it seems fine.  Stylistically I'd put the `RUN npm install` before the `COPY . .` (to improve cache utilization on rebuild) and not `RUN npm install -g` anything not listed in your `package.json` file, but as is I'd expect it to do what you want.

Comment: My container is not starting it is crashing. I will update this question with the error. @DavidMaze

Comment: @DavidMaze I have updated the question with new changes to `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml`